# Name is not XML Namespace compliant

Tags: r, rvest, xml2

I'm trying to read the table on this site:

http://spacefem.com/pregnant/due.php?use=EDD&m=09&d=10&y=16

I use `rvest`, but quickly get an error:

```
library(rvest)
read_html("http://spacefem.com/pregnant/due.php?use=EDD&m=09&d=10&y=16")
```

> Error: Name spoiler:3tbt4d3m is not XML Namespace compliant [202]

What does this error mean, and is there anything I can do to get around it?

I've gotten as far as pinpointing the internal function causing the error: `xml2:::doc_parse_raw`. However, `xml2:::doc_parse_raw` is simply a call to internal C code, making debugging of this issue substantially more difficult.

Comment: It looks like there's a malformed tag in there that's causing problems, specifically `<spoiler:3tbt4d3m>`. It doesn't contain the table, so you could probably regex it out if you grab the HTML with `httr::GET` or similar, but there may be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `htmltidy` (need to use v0.3.0 or higher which means—as of the date of this answer—using the development version vs CRAN version until CRAN is up to 0.3.0+) to "clean" the document:

```
library(rvest)
library(htmltidy) # devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/htmltidy")
library(httr)

URL <- "http://spacefem.com/pregnant/due.php?use=EDD&m=09&d=10&y=16"

# the site was not returning content for me w/o a more browser-like user agent

res <- GET(URL, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36"))

cleaned <- tidy_html(content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8"),
                     list(TidyDocType="html5"))

pg <- read_html(cleaned)
```

Comment: awesome! happy to have helped the package. hope it didn't cause too many headaches!

Answer (score 2):

The HTML contains a malformed tag that's causing problems, specifically `<spoiler:3tbt4d3m>`, as the error suggests. If you grab the HTML with httr without parsing it, you can use regex to remove that tag and its contents without incident, as a quick look reveals that it doesn't contain the table.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

url <- 'http://spacefem.com/pregnant/due.php?use=EDD&m=09&d=10&y=16'

html <- url %>% GET(user_agent('R')) %>% content('text')

html2 <- gsub('<spoiler:3tbt4d3m>.*</spoiler:3tbt4d3m>', '', html)

df <- html2 %>% read_html() %>% 
    html_node(xpath = '//table[@border="1"]') %>% 
    # obviously insufficient to parse double headers, but at least the data exists now
    html_table(fill = TRUE)

df[1:5, 1:3]
##                        Date Progress Overall probability ofspontaneous labor
## 1                      Date Progress                            On this date
## 2 Saturday August 6th, 2016  35W, 0D                                   0.01%
## 3   Sunday August 7th, 2016  35W, 1D                                   0.01%
## 4   Monday August 8th, 2016  35W, 2D                                   0.02%
## 5  Tuesday August 9th, 2016  35W, 3D                                   0.02%
```

Mixing regex and HTML makes me a bit uneasy, so maybe there's a cleaner way of tidying, but before parsing I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: Thanks! Certainly not a very helpful error message for identifying the problem. Had no idea to even search for spoiler in the XML code...

Comment: Yeah, it only really makes sense in retrospect, and would be much improved by mentioning it's a tag. I only found it because I thought the `3tbt4d3m` part was odd, so I searched the HTML for it.

Comment: With [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) in mind, I'll hold off on accepting a regex-based answer for now, though it certainly works.

Comment: Ha, that post is ridiculous. And understood; I'd avoid it if I knew of an alternative.